# SQL, JOIN?.. information from three tables

Tags: sql, join

There are tables `orders`, `shipping_types`, and `shipping_modules`

How can I print information from the table `orders`, and *one field* from the table `shipping_modules`?

```
where 
    o.shipping_type_id = st.shipping_type_id 
and st.shipping_module_id = sm_shipping_module_id
```

That is, JOIN here like you can not use because there are used in conjunction, not two but three tables.

Comment: I don't understand, you don't wanna use join?

Comment: Man, the immense amounts of answers you get when you paste that exact title in SO's search box: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=SQL%2C+JOIN%3F..+information+from+three+tables

Comment: @GolezTrol I better ask ,than I will look for something that I need a translating into its own language each question. This is not such a big tragedy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, join is still allowed here. You can join multiple tables if you want.

```
SELECT  a.*, c.shipping_module_id
FROM    orders a
        INNER JOIN shipping_types b
            ON a.shipping_type_id = b.shipping_type_id
        INNER JOIN shipping_modules c
            ON b.shipping_module_id = c.shipping_module_id
```

*just change `c.shipping_module_id` to your desired column name to show.*

Answer (score 1):

You can `JOIN` as many tables as you need and only use the fields that you need to display in your `SELECT`.
I.e.

```
SELECT table1.fld1, table3.fld3
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON ...
JOIN table3 ON ...
...
```